# Solving Navier Stokes Eq using Gauss–Seidel and Finite Difference

Tags: navier-stokes

I am trying to solve the following set of equations using a finite-difference approach and an iterative solver (Gauss-Seidel).

Continuity Equation:

$\frac{\partial V_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial V_y}{\partial y} = 0$

Simplified Stokes-Equation:

$ \eta (\frac{\partial^2 V_x}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 V_x}{\partial y^2}) - \frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = 0$

$ \eta (\frac{\partial^2 V_y}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 V_y}{\partial y^2}) - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}+ \rho g = 0$

Should I use both Stokes equations to solve for velocity ($v_x,v_y$). However, how can I solve then for pressure ($P$)? Or do I first solve for velocity using the continuity equation and eventually I solve for pressure using the stokes equations?

Comment: I would recommend solving all the equations coupled together.  While this slightly complicates the coding since you have to keep your unknowns straight, it is more true to the solver and many of your equations simply wouldn't be asked.  So solve all three at node 1, then all three at node 2, using the values from node 1, then all three at node 3 ...

Comment: @GodricSeer The method you describe is a "Vanka smoother", see his 1986 paper "Block-implicit multigrid solution of Navier-Stokes equations in primitive variables".

Answer (score 1):

In the incompressible Stokes (and Navier-Stokes) equations, pressure serves to enforce incompressibility. You have 3 equations for three unknown field variables ($V_x$, $V_y$, and $P$) so your system is fully determined once you choose boundary conditions. There is no additional equation for pressure.

In solving the time-dependent Navier-Stokes equations, a popular technique is to use a predictor/corrector type method where the velocities are advanced based on the old pressure values and then corrected using a "pressure projection" technique. This involves solving a Poisson equation to find the required pressure to enforce incompressibility. This essentially means projecting the updated velocity field onto the space of incompressible velocity fields where the pressure field serves to enforce this projection.

In your case, the Stokes equations can be discretized using your desired method, resulting in a system of linear equations that can be solved simultaneously using your desired matrix inversion technique or iterative scheme. I'm not sure how well behaved the resulting linear system will be in terms of convergence under Gauss-Seidel iteration. It may work fine or you may need to perform some type of pre-conditioning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to solve a simple two-dimensional problem. In this case I would strongly recommend you to use a formulation of the equation which use the out-of-plane component of the vorticity and the streamfunction.